# What would be a good name for a function that interprets a string to try to access an attribute?

Tags: python, function, parsing, attributes

This is a sort of reverse-question. I have a function that does roughly what I want and I want to know what to formally call what it is that I am doing, or what I should name the function.

The function takes a string and interprets that string to attempt to access an attribute of some object instance. For example, if it spots square brackets at the end of the string, it assumes the attribute is an iterable object and it tries to access the appropriate element of that attribute. The function also has a default imputation value that it returns if it finds that the attribute is missing.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

class Event(object):
    pass

event = Event()
event.b = [10, 20, 30]
event.c = 15

def get_attribute_by_name(
    object_instance          = None,
    name                     = None,
    imputation_default_value = -9
    ):

    try:
        if "[" in name and "]" in name:
            index = int(name.split("[")[1].split("]")[0])
            attribute = name.split("[")[0]
            value = getattr(object_instance, attribute)[index]
        else:
            value = getattr(object_instance, name)
    except:
        value = imputation_default_value

    return value

print(get_attribute_by_name(object_instance = event, name = "b[2]"))
print(get_attribute_by_name(object_instance = event, name = "b"))
print(get_attribute_by_name(object_instance = event, name = "c"))
print(get_attribute_by_name(object_instance = event, name = "d"))
```

output:

```
30
[10, 20, 30]
15
-9
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually a built-in function `getattr` does almost the same thing, and you could replace the built-in function with yours.

See [getattr](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#getattr)